# Cant get opera to use flash on Linux mint ulyssa 20.1

Tags: adobe-flash

I want to use opera but cant get it to display video. How do I get it to allow flash.Can I download flash to get it to work or do I need to do something else.

Comment: What do you get in Opera for the following: `opera://settings/content/flash?search=flash`? If you get some info, [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1618948/edit) a screenshot of the entire result page to your post.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1616866/use-flash-player-after-12-jan-2021

Answer (score 0):

Flash player's support has officially ended. You should not be using it anymore, and in fact in most browsers you cannot use it, to the point where they do not allow you to use it.

You shouldn't need to download and install anything else for the video to work, assuming whatever version of Opera you're using is up to date and the website that hosts the video actually works properly.