# Instant Demo requires Adobe Flash Player to be installed

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, flash

I have installed all adobe flash version, for chrome, firefox or internet explorer
I downloaded this software, Instant Demo
https://www.instant-demo.com/download.php

But when I launch it - it return me this message: ***Instant Demo requires Adobe Flash Player to be installed***
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXPrx.png)

But this is not possible because I have installed Adobe Flash

I try to follow this tutorial
[Use Flash Player after 12 Jan 2021](https://superuser.com/questions/1616866/use-flash-player-after-12-jan-2021)

but seems doesn't work, however I have not found any Flash32_32_0_0_453.ocx or Flash64 are missing.

Comment: Adobe Flash is permanently gone.  Use this post   https://meta.superuser.com/questions/14418/what-should-we-do-with-flash-shockwave-questions

Comment: That's really not a product you ought to be considering purchasing. Even if you get it to work, no-one you publish for will be able to use it… because Flash is gone, world-wide, cross-platform. The last gasp tidy-up on 12 Jan was merely the end of a long, slow death for Flash, which has been coming for over 10 years. [I banned it from the entire building here in 2015].

Comment: I download Macromedia from here
http://www.oldversion.com/windows/macromedia-flash-player-10

I install *flashplayer10_1r53_64_winax* and after that the error message vanished.