# Open local html file with flash file

Tags: html, flash, swf, html-files

I have an old html file, how can I open local html file with flash file on my computer in 2021? Before adobe flash take down, I can open it, it is easy but now I can't open it. Please help

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I don't know if this answer will be helpful to you: https://superuser.com/questions/1616866/use-flash-player-after-12-jan-2021/1617236#1617236 because I checked it only with online pages containing Flash content, not for local files. But maybe `AllowListUrlPattern=file:///` in `mms.cfg` (or specifying the exact path to .swf file) will work. Alternatively, you may run the .swf file alone via standalone Flash Player. This still works and the standalone Flash Player can still be downloaded from Adobe: https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to google something like "play flash" or "open page with flash"?

Basically just open the page in your browser. Even if it doesn't play the flash content anymore, it might allow you to download it as a new .sfw file to your desktop. Sfw files you can play with a [Flash player emulator](https://nosamu.medium.com/flash-player-emulators-how-to-play-swfs-in-2021-and-beyond-d56c3899b7e6).

If that isn't working, Browserstack has an [online test platform](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/test-on-older-browser-versions) for developers to test how their content behaves in older browsers. That might work.

If that's not working either, you can download an install [an older version of a browser](https://ngyikp.com/download-old-browser-versions/) and test with that.

If the content is a game, I'd check if it was included in [BlueMaxima's Flashpoint](https://bluemaxima.org/flashpoint/).

Comment: I tried all your solution but they doesn't work. What else?

Comment: @user1516303 Have you checked the solutions from my comment above too?

Comment: I don't know where is the mms.cfg file lies and how to access it. Please help

Comment: Please note: this isn't a technical support phone line, this is a community. You don't get a single person to help you out. Consequently you shouldn't ask/answer in comments - you should edit your original posting by adding new details. Exactly which older browser/version you tried in Browserstack? What older browser/version you installed? Did you add flash player to the older version? Which Flash emulator did you try? Did you try @raj's suggestions? What exactly were the results? Upload screenshots to imgur or similar and add the links to the question.

Comment: ... did you try googling what mms.cfg file is?

Comment: @user1516303 I linked you a full answer with exact location of `mms.cfg` file and description of it's contents. Plus there are many other answers in the linked page that you can try. If you wan't to do nonstandard things (and what you want to do is  nonstandard, just because Adobe decided to block Flash ;)), you have to **think** and try things yourself - you can't expect to have a "ready" recipe you can just "blindly" follow.